# Guidewire message queues

Tags: guidewire

I am trying to edit the guidewire message queue name. I see that the queue names are in the messaging-config.xml. Is there any impact on changing the guidewire queue name? The names don't seem to be used anywhere else in the code, only the messaging-config.xml.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

As far as I know, there is no impact in renaming the queue name. There could be some impact if you are changing the destination Id or any event names. The destination ID or event names might be used for conditional checks inside the event fired rule sets.

But renaming message queue names does not have any impact as such. Ensure to check if you have any queue names written inside the overridden methods of transport plugin (methods like shutdown, resume, suspend)

Comment: Thank you for the response, Arun.